# windows command not working when it is run through bat script. when it is executed directly on command line it works. Added the output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
C:\Users
|      ATT.bat
|
+---A
|      ABC.exe
|
\---B
       BCD.exe
```

When I run this command directly in a `cmd.exe` window with `C:\Users` as the current directory:

```bash
B\BCD.exe --subsystem  --server_address 127.127.128.1 --server_port 1515 -c B\config.json.
```

It is working, I get a `cmd.exe` window opened, showing the details of its connection, server adress,  and port address.

output:

```
QoS compute crc, QoS check crc: (OFF, OFF)
[19:21:17.225963] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: CertificateStatus
[19:21:17.226971] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: GetCSR
[19:21:17.226971] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: GetCSRResponse
[19:21:17.226971] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: WriteCertificate
[19:21:17.226971] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: WriteCertificateResponse
[19:21:17.226971] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: CertificateValidityStatus
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: SigningApproval
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: WriteApproval
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: GetCachedData
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: CachedData
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: UserAuthorizationRequest
[19:21:17.228006] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: CachedComponentData
[19:21:17.228472] (0x00004870) [info] Registering DDS Type: ClearNodeCache
```

When I run the following command via the `ATT.bat` file the commands are displayed but  doesn't show me any output related to `BCD.exe`.

```bash
start /wait B\BCD.exe --subsystem  --server_address 127.127.128.1 --server_port 1515 -c B\config.json
```

I would like to understand what the issue is when the `.bat` file command is being run. Why is it not working? Am I doing anything wrong. Please guys let me know.

Comment: It's really hard to say what's going on here without any code for context.

Comment: at a glance - may be the batch is executed with admin permissions and is executed by default in system32 ?